# redux devtools not showing state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

can anybody please tell me why is my redux app not working? I have been going step by step from tutorial from youtube but my state isn't event shown in redux dev tools. All I have there is 'states are equal'.

**counter.js file (reducer)**

```
const counterReducer = (state = 0, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT':
            return state + 1;
    
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default counterReducer;
```

**index.js file**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

//reducer
import counterReducer from './Reducers/counter';

//store
import {createStore} from 'redux';

//provider
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const store = createStore(
  counterReducer,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the action dispatched in the devtools (raw you can just copy and paste it). Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: No, there are not errors, I'm pretty new to Redux, I have not used actions yet. This will be simple counter app as Redux made for explanation in their docs. I'm pretty dumb because I've noticed I had opened 'Diff' tab instead of 'State' tab. I think that's sign it's enough learning for today.. But if you can help me with one more thing. There is (pin) : 0 in my 'State' tab.. How can I change it to Count : 0?

Comment: @Pinncik can you please mark my answer correct if it helped solve your issue

Answer (score 6):

try this code below in your index.js file.

```
    import { createStore, compose } from 'redux';    

    const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
    
    const store = createStore(
      counterReducer,
      composeEnhancers()
    );
```

and if you are using any middleware like redux-thunk, then do as following,

```
    import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';

    const store = createStore(
      rootReducer,
      composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
    );
```

Comment: This worked for me but why do we have to manually add the comoseEnhancers just to see out instance?

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to change from "Autoselect instances" in the right upper corner to my own instance. The state was 'hidden' and that's why I couldn't see it despite configured everything correctly.

[image: autoselect instances]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update anything inside redux store then you have to dispatch an action mandatorily. Create an action, dispatch that action from your component. Then you will see everything working.

Answer (score 0):

The above rated solution is accurate, but we have some cases when we don't want the end users to see our state using React DevTools. For example, in a production environment, we don't want this to happen. To implement this functionality use this chunk of code.

```
import { createStore, compose } from 'redux';   
// if env is not equal to 'production', show state in Redux DevTools
const composeEnhancers = (process.env.REACT_APP_NODE_ENV !== 'production' && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__) || compose;
const store = createStore(counterReducer,composeEnhancers());
// rest of the code goes here...
```